# How can I add new udev rules for a ftdi-sio device?

Tags: ubuntu, rules, udev, ftdi

I am trying to add the following file to /etc/udev/rules.d:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="FAC6", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe ftdi_sio" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0403 FAC6 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id'"
```

and then I write in terminal `sudo service udev restart` to reload the new rule.

I unpluged and pluged again the device and it doesn't recognize it as FTDI-SIO device. What must I do?

The output when I plug it and execute on terminal `dmesg` is:

```
[ 1469.235761] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 1469.392269] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=fac6
[ 1469.392278] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1469.392284] usb 1-3: Product: USB2-F-7001 CAN-Plus Adapter
[ 1469.392289] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: EasySync
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the device is USB2-F-7001.

Best regards.
Alessandro

Comment: Hello, did you check out the https://superuser.com/ side? Your question should meet its scope more than the scope of this side. Chances are that the answer you are looking for is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule syntax looks correct to me, I've just successfully done something very similar with identical syntax and just a different product_id.

**what's the name of your rules file?**

It should be `<number>-<description>.rules`

e.g. /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-can.rules

Comment: Hello. The name of my udev rules is 95-ftdipid.rules. That is the name with which the company send me the file.